# How to Call an azure Function just using the Azure SDK as in AWS?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Recently i have been working with Azure Functions, I am totally new in this world but in my current job they are trying to migrate an specific Lambda Function to Azure Function.

They have this lambda without any public endpoint and the only way to use it is something like this with an clientID and SecretID:

```
InvokeResponse result = LambdaClient.InvokeAsync(new InvokeRequest
                {
                    FunctionName = lambdaName,
                    InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse,
                    Payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param)
                }).Result;
```

They are not using any URL to get the result, just the AWS SDK and credentials, this is just called internally.

Sooo.. my question: Is there any way to configure and consume an Azure Function in the same way?

thanks!

1. I created an HTTP Azure Function and it worked using an HTTP CLIENT and the URL but this is exactly what they are avoiding.
2. I Closed all the public traffic towards my AzureFunction and i have tried using the Azure SDK with Azure Authenticate

```
var clientId = "xxClientID";
    var clientSecret = "xxClientSecret";
    var tenantId = "xxTenantID";
   var subscriptionId = "xxSubsID";

    // Auth , and client
    var credentials = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId,    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    var azure = Azure.Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

    // Get azure function
    var functionName = "functionName";
    var resourceGroupName = "resourceGroupName";

    var functionApp  = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, functionName);
```

But apparently this is just something to start or stop the function and not to consume data, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing authentication with triggers. Azure Functions (like AWS Lamba) use a variety of triggers to start the function execution, with HTTP being just one of many. You can read more about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp 

Skimming the AWS docs I suspect under the covers `LambdaClient.InvokeAsync` is doing a HTTP post.